# Function .assigned() in lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list (called: `profile_list`) of type Tuple, index 100 and size 8, like:

```
[(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 
 (2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8), 
 ...]
```

I have another list (called: `People`) of 100 names of people, like:

```
['Lakisha Gosse', 
 'Maurine Pace', 
 'Marianne Hankinson', 
 ...]
```

I want to combine (I think with .append()) these list. Thus in this example,

```
[(Lakisha Gosse: (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)), 
 (Maurine Pace: (2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8)), 
 ...]
```

I tried:

```
for name in People: 
    for people in range(len(profile_list)):
        for profile in profile_list[people][0:]:
            profile.append(name)
```

But this gives me an error: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'. Sometimes it works, but then it adds the row of 8 numbers as a new index in the list of people, which will create a list of 200 instead of 100. Can anyone help?

Comment: `list(zip(People, profile_list))`?

Comment: `for profile in profile_list[people][0:]:` will just loop over the integer of the array, so `profile`is an integer, to which you can't add anything.

Comment: yes, the zip works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can have a list of dicts using list comprehension :

```
[{p: pl} for p, pl in zip(People, profile_list)]
```

output example:

```
[{'Lakisha Gosse': (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)}, {'Maurine Pace': (2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)}]
```

or, if you want to have only tuples:

```
[(p, pl) for p, pl in zip(People, profile_list)]
```

same as above using built-in class `list`:

```
list(zip(People, profile_list))
```

output:

```
[('Lakisha Gosse', (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)), ('Maurine Pace', (2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))]
```